# TabControl.SelectedItem not a TabItem? RelativeSource binding failing

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, tabcontrol, relativesource

I'm trying something with TabControl and am flummoxed by this

```
<TabControl Name="MainControl">
    <TabItem Header="MyTab1">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Path=SelectedItem.Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabControl}}"/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Modules" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource tabItemControl}"/>
</TabControl>
```

this works as expected.

However this :

```
<TabControl Name="MainControl">
    <TabItem Header="MyTab1">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Path=Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabItem}}"/>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Modules" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource tabItemControl}"/>
</TabControl>
```

does not.

Any idea why?

Is the selectedItem not a TabItem? Is there something different in the hierarchy?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394302/relativesource-in-datatemplate-works-with-tabcontrol-but-not-with-tabitem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown in the post [RelativeSource in DataTemplate works with TabControl but not with TabItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394302/relativesource-in-datatemplate-works-with-tabcontrol-but-not-with-tabitem) the TabItem and SelectedContent are hosted in different panels hence SelectedItem.Header is not working as it's not actually a tabItem

Posting the snoop image from the earlier post below
[image]