# WPF xaml, have child element inherit parent property

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to get a child element to inherit the color from it's parent Tab Item. So instead of having to set each background color individually I can just set the tabitem color and it will do the rest for me. I have tried many different things, but nothing works. In VS, with the code posted below, when I have the ScrollViewer selected and in the properties window click go to source in the background color binding, it highlights the tabitem background property, but the color does not change. Sorry, I've just started picking up xaml just the other day.

```
 <TabItem Name="PD" Header="Product Details" Background="#FFB5CFE2"  FontFamily="Vrinda" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="750" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-4,-5,-4,-4" Background="{Binding Background, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=TabItem}}">....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the application, the output window in VS can display binding errors. You probably have one saying: "System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TabItem', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=Background; DataItem=null; target element is 'ScrollViewer' (Name=''); target property is 'Background' (type 'Brush')"

Basically what is happening is the TabItem and the content of the tab are separated in the visual tree and you won't be able to find the TabItem itself from the TabContent by looking back up the tree. See this SO answer for a visual explanation : [RelativeSource in DataTemplate works with TabControl but not with TabItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394302/relativesource-in-datatemplate-works-with-tabcontrol-but-not-with-tabitem)

You have a couple of options from here that I would suggest,

- Reference the TabItem by element name:

  `<ScrollViewer Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=PD}">`
- Create a static resource and use it amongst the items:

  `<SolidColorBrush Color="#FFB5CFE2" x:Key="PDBackgroundBrush"/>
   <ScrollViewer Background="{StaticResource PDBackgroundBrush}"/>`

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get it to work using the name reference, but was kind of hoping against it, because then I'd have to go and change the referenced name in the scrollviewer every time i create a new tab. However, looking back at it, I'd have to inset the bind event regardless, and I guess i can spare and extra 2 seconds to change the name. Thanks again!