# RelativeSource binding does not work

Tags: wpf

The first textbox below cannot find the parent TabItem however the second textbox can.  What am I doing wrong in the first binding?

```
<TabItem Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyle}" x:Name="zzzzz">
   <StackPanel >
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}, Path=IsSelected}"></TextBlock>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=zzzzz, Path=IsSelected}" />
   </StackPanel>
</TabItem>
```

The error message is: System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TabItem', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=IsSelected; DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

I've never had to set AncestorLevel but I tried setting it to 5000 it still does not work.

Note that I am not setting the binding from the DataTemplate as is shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394302/relativesource-in-datatemplate-works-with-tabcontrol-but-not-with-tabitem).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394302/relativesource-in-datatemplate-works-with-tabcontrol-but-not-with-tabitem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RelativeSource in DataTemplate works with TabControl but not with TabItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394302/relativesource-in-datatemplate-works-with-tabcontrol-but-not-with-tabitem)

Comment: @FoggyFinder Thank you - I saw this but I do not understand how it applies to my scenario. I am in fact finding the TabItem as is evidenced by the second TextBlock.

Comment: @ASh see updated question.

Comment: @mm8 Yes one TextBlock that reads true - the second one.  I reprod this on my work computer - just create a new proj and in MainWindow add a TabControl.  Paste in code from question.  First TextBlock is empty.  Removing style makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `TabItem` is not a visual ancestor of the `TextBlock` in the *content* panel of the `TabControl` so your first binding won't ever work.

If you put a `TextBlock` in the *header* of a `TabItem`, you can bind to the latter using a `{RelativeSource}`. But the currently visible content panel is a visual child of the `TabContol` itself rather than a specific `TabItem`.

Comment: I suppose the key word here is "visual" since the second binding in my question works fine.  Thanks for your answer.